# Mount react-admin under /admin

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

I simply want all of my admin pages to be under `/admin`.

```js
<Admin
  title="Admin"
  dashboard={Dashboard}
  dataProvider={restClient}
  history={history}
>
  <Resource
    name="users"
    list={UserList}
  />
</Admin>
```

My main page is at `/admin` but when I click Users in the sidebar, it changes the path to `/users` and not `/admin/users`.

I'm using react-admin 2.0.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key is actually in the history prop passed to the Admin component:

```js
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory({ basename: '/admin' });

<Admin history={history} />
```

Answer (score 2):

react-router v4 expects a `basename` prop to arrange what you desire. More info [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths).

It's not clear that react-admin exposes a way for you to provide this, at least I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

We had to use nginx and host two completely different apps to do this. It does not seem easy at all to integrate react-admin with another application already using react-router. The documentation provides some help, but the documentation also is often difficult to follow so I was very trepidatious of copying and pasting it's code to try and do this.

Ovverall I've been more frustrated with react-admin the longer I use it; I think there are some great things about the project but the documentation is not well-organized, there's no easy-to-read API reference, and there are a lot of leaky abstractions in that you really have to understand the material-ui, react-final-forms, and of course react-router packages to do anything even remotely 'outside the box' with react-admin.

Sorry to vent, but, my two cents is, split the app or use a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is going to work for all versions.
In my case, the solution with history has not worked.
I've done the following approach:

```js
<Admin basename="/admin">
```

Comment: This was already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50487324/337446)